# Warning to flag potential type incompatibility

Tags: python, types, warnings

Which warning should I use to flag-off a potential type incompatibility?

My specific use case is the following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ColName': [10, 20, 60, 70],
                   'Col2': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]})
lookup_val = ['10','20']
filter = filter_df(df, 'ColName', lookup_val)
#filter_df is a custom function which filters the df based values & column name
```

I want to warn the user that strings are being looked up in a column which has numeric values. I looked at the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/warnings.html#warning-categories) and `RuntimeWarning` seems to come closest. I also looked at other Python packages, they seem to usually subclass the base `Warning` class. Not sure if it matters a whole lot but I was just curious if there is a 'correct' answer.

Here's what I want to do:

```
if looking_up_strings_in_column_with_numbers:
     warnings.warn('looking up strings in numbers', CustomWarningClass) 
     #CustomWarningClass could be a subclass of Warning or maybe RuntimeWarning. My question is which one?
```

Comment: TypeError would be best if the method would cease to function correctly if given those values

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand your question right, but you only should use exceptions for unexpected / unintended behaviour; not for general warnings getting raised whenever some code is run.

Comment: The function shouldn't terminate execution. I want it to Warn and continue executing. I use `df.query` inside `filter_df` which handles this without raising an exception.

Comment: I don't understand how you want to use a exception for your problem. Could you show us how the code would look using a simple `Exception`?